# Run java class from cmd with full path?

Tags: java, cmd

I have compile a java file

```
javac XSDValidator.java
```

And I get a XSDValidator.class

Lets say I have the the class (`XSDValidatorc.class`) file in

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\xsd_validtion
```

And I write this in cmd

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\xsd_validtion> java XSDValidator students.xsd students.xml
```

It works fine. But its not working if I I'am in another directory and want to run the file with absolute path. Why doesn't it work?

Lite this, lets say I'am in the directory

```
C:\aaa\User\Document
```

And write like this it's not working.

```
java C:\xampp\htdocs\xsd_validtion\XSDValidator C:\xampp\htdocs\xsd_validtion\students.xsd C:\xampp\htdocs\xsd_validtion\students.xml
```

This is the java-file

```
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/xsd/xsd_validation.htm
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.xml.XMLConstants;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource;

import javax.xml.validation.Schema;
import javax.xml.validation.SchemaFactory;
import javax.xml.validation.Validator;

import org.xml.sax.SAXException;

public class XSDValidator {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      if(args.length !=2){
         System.out.println("Usage : XSDValidator <file-name.xsd> <file-name.xml>" );
      } else {
         boolean isValid = validateXMLSchema(args[0],args[1]);

         if(isValid){
            System.out.println(args[1] + " is valid against " + args[0]);
         } else {
            System.out.println(args[1] + " is not valid against " + args[0]);
         }
      }
   }

   public static boolean validateXMLSchema(String xsdPath, String xmlPath){
      try {
         SchemaFactory factory =
            SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);
            Schema schema = factory.newSchema(new File(xsdPath));
            Validator validator = schema.newValidator();
            validator.validate(new StreamSource(new File(xmlPath)));
      } catch (IOException e){
         System.out.println("Exception: "+e.getMessage());
         return false;
      }catch(SAXException e1){
         System.out.println("SAX Exception: "+e1.getMessage());
         return false;
      }

      return true;

   }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use the java classpath:

```
java -cp C:\xampp\htdocs\xsd_validtion\ XSDValidator C:\xampp\htdocs\xsd_validtion\students.xsd C:\xampp\htdocs\xsd_validtion\students.xml
```

This includes the directory where the class file is located to the classpath.

directories in java are package structures. Thats why you can not use it as a normal Path

Answer (score 0):

The answer from Jens

```
java -cp C:\xampp\htdocs\xsd_validtion\ XSDValidator C:\xampp\htdocs\xsd_validtion\students.xsd C:\xampp\htdocs\xsd_validtion\students.xml
```

can be the accepted one. I just want to give another solution, in some situations, it's better

```
CD C:\xampp\htdocs\xsd_validtion

java XSDValidator students.xsd students.xml

CD C:\aaa\User\Document
```

Comment: *in some situations, it's better* in which? BTW That is teh solution which is suggested by OP in the question as workingsolution

Comment: Just think about the problem a little bit easier, for example, he has more than 1 application to execute, he has many input, output files. It's a bad idea to put C:\xampp\htdocs\xsd_validtion\ before every parameters. He said he is in another directory, but is it mandatory? Maybe no, so I would say he just needs to CD the application directory and cd back when the job is done.

Comment: *he has more than 1 application to execute*  you cant run more tahn one application with one java command

Comment: I agree with your solution, If I answer first, I would answer the same. That why I mentioned it in my answer and also vote up your answer.

Comment: *It's a bad idea to put C:\xampp\htdocs\xsd_validtion\ before every parameters* it depends on.Maybe it is only for simplyfing. The foles can be in different folders. Also you can use variables to store the path

Comment: Yes, but he can execute in many java commands. I'm being bored with this discussion.

Comment: Yes, I didn't say we can't us variables. And it would can be

java <app> %FOLDER%\file1 %FOLDER%\file2 %FOLDER%\file3 %FOLDER%\file4 %FOLDER%\file5 ....

But we can remove all %FOLDER% by CD to the %FOLDER%

Comment: You need to use `cd /D` rather than `cd` in order to safely work even if you are currently working on another drive...